# Searching particular word in a non-delimited string

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, pattern-matching

I have a large document containing string like this, basically a non-delimited string -
mynameisjohnsmith

I also have a collection of names, this could be really large, assume a million records. What I intend to do it to check if the document contains a name that is available in the collection. One way to do it is to index the document and iterate over the collection and for each entry search the index for the name. This could be really inefficient in case the names is not there in the collection (1 million iterations).

I am wondering if there are better ways of doing it. Something like indexing both the document and the names and finding an intersection.
Thanks.

Comment: Best way forward is using solr/lucene, imo., But look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633286/efficient-substring-search-in-a-large-text-file-containing-100-millions-strings

Comment: `This could be really inefficient in case the names is not there in the collection` - probably not if you're using the right index.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself one way might be to split the document into words and build some map with the word being the key (the value might be position information etc.). Then look up the names in that map which would be close to O(1) if the maps are set up accordingly in terms of initial capacity etc.

Comment: Look up the Aho-Corasick or MRSI algorithms.

Comment: @Thomas: How do I know where to break, the data is non- delimited :(

Comment: Being that you've tagged Lucene, if you go that route, analyzing with [NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html) would probably be the way to go about it..

Comment: @David Conrad: Aho-Corasick does exactly what I wanted and with O(n). If you can add that as an answer, I will be pleased to accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: @User2709 Sorry, I didn't come back for a long time. I've posted it as an answer, finally.

Answer (score 0):

The [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) string searching algorithm uses a finite state machine to search for a large number of strings simultaneously in a document. The complexity of the algorithm is linear in the length of the strings plus the length of the searched text plus the number of output matches. It's how virus scanning software is able to efficiently search for a large number of virus signatures in files in reasonable time.